# cross validation in lasso problem

Tags: regression, cross-validation, lasso, regularization

Let us consider the following lasso estimator:
$$
\hat{\beta}_{L} = \arg\min \, \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}^{n}||y_{i} - \textbf{x}_{i}\beta||_{2}^{2} + \frac{\lambda_{n}}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{p}|\beta_{j}|
$$
and assume that $p$, the dimension of parameter, is fixed, smaller than $n$ and the design matrix $\textbf{X}$ is not singular and
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\textbf{x}_{i}\textbf{x}_{i}^{T} \to C,
$$
where $C$ is positive definite matrix and
$$
\frac{1}{n} \max_{1\leq i \leq n}\textbf{x}_{i}^{T} \textbf{x}_{i} \to 0.
$$
(note: the conditions on the design matrix are taken from famous Fu & Knight paper ["Asymptotics for lasso-type estimators"](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1015957397) (2000)).

Next, assume that for each $n$ we choose $\lambda_{n}$ by leave-one-out cross validation for $l_{2}$-norm.

What can we say about the sequence $\lambda_{n}$? Is it faster than $O(\sqrt{n})$?

Please, feel free to choose the design matrix $\textbf{X}$ as simple as possible, i.e. the diagonal matrix for repeated balances measurements.

Comment: You can't say anything about the sequence until you indicate exactly how $\mathbf X$ varies with $n.$

Comment: Dear @whuber, I have edited the question.

Comment: Thank you--that is much clearer.  But in light of those particular asymptotics, wouldn't you expect $\lambda_n$ to *decrease* with $n$?

Comment: Dear @whuber, actually, I am interested if the convergence is faster than $O(\sqrt{n})$, which would be enough for $\sqrt{n}$ consistency.

Comment: I believe you mean $O(1/\sqrt{n}),$ then.  $O(\sqrt{n})$ would *diverge.*

Comment: Dear @whuber, I am confused now. For consistency it is enough that $\frac{\lambda_{n}}{\sqrt{n}} \to c \geq 0$, according to the paper I am referencing to.

Comment: I don't see how that is possible, because diverging $\lambda_n$ would drive $\hat\beta$ to zero.

Comment: Dear @whuber, I apologise. I forgot to devide $\lambda_{n}$ by $n$ in the criterion function. Thank you!

Comment: +1.  But you could dispense with the $1/n$ factors altogether if you like, because they will not change the estimates.

Comment: Dear @whuber, yes, of course, it is done in order to have criterion function bounded.

Comment: @ABK , I see the bounty has expired and you got no answer. I deleted my answer because it's a bit more difficult than a simple shrinking. The factor by which the shrinking occurs is a constant shift, which is independent from the scale of the $\beta_{OLS}$ (in my answer I assumed a scaling instead of a shift). The leave one out cross validation will get to a non-zero $\lambda$ when there is a sign change in a coefficient for some of the folds (which may occur with some probability if the true $\beta$ is zero). I hope I will find time to work this out in an answer.